# How, to interpret the geometry of a 2nd degree polynomial equation, which contains an elliptic quadratic form and whose constant coefficient is zero?

Tags: geometry, polynomials, conic-sections, quadratic-forms

$$
\mathbf x =    \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y 
    \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf T
$$
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B/2 \\
    B/2 & C
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Eigendecomposition of $Q$:
$
~Q = \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf e_1 & \mathbf e_2 
    \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf T \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1 & 0 \\
    0 & \lambda_2
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf e_1 & \mathbf e_2 
    \end{bmatrix}
$

$$
0 \lt \lambda_1 \le \lambda_2
$$
$$
\mathbf e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    e_1 &  e_2 
    \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf T
$$
$$
\alpha = \arctan \frac{e_2}{e_1}
$$
$$
\mathbf T =    \begin{bmatrix}
    h & k 
    \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf T
$$
$$
\mathbf x^\mathsf T Q \mathbf x + \mathbf T^\mathsf T \mathbf x = 1 \label{a}\tag{1}
$$
Equation (1) is a 2nd degree polynomial equation whose geometry I can interpret and for which I can get a definite parameterization. If I am not mistaken, the ellipse defined in (1) is parameterized as:
$$
\mathcal E = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\
    -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac {1}{\sqrt \lambda_1} \cos t \\ \frac {1}{\sqrt \lambda_2} \sin t
    \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    h \\ k
    \end{bmatrix} ~;~ 0 \le t \lt 2 \pi
$$
Now let's consider another second degree polynomial equation.
$$
\mathbf x^\mathsf T Q \mathbf x + \mathbf T^\mathsf T \mathbf x = 0 \label{b}\tag{2}
$$
I can neither get a parameterization for, nor can I interpret the geometry of the curve defined by equation (2). Here is the question: How does the curve defined in equation (2) get parameterized and/or what are the geometric properties of that curve?

Comment: Note that (1) doesn't necessarily define an ellipse.
 $T$ defines a translation. This webpage can help http://mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html

Comment: I have edited the original post by applying restrictions to the eigenvalues, such that the quadratic form is necessarily elliptic.

Comment: That webpage does not seem to treat the case where the constant coefficient in the 2nd degree polynomial equation is zero.

Comment: Climb back down the tech tree for a moment. What is $$\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 0$$ the equation of? What happens when add $+cx + dy$ to the lh side?

Comment: Perhaps if after adding $ +hx + ky$ to the LHS, I were to complete the square(s), then I would (magically) receive a polynomial equation of degree two in the variables $\left ( x-h \right )$ and $\left ( y-k \right )$. In this new polynomial equation there would be coefficients of zero at the linear terms and there would be a non-zero coefficient at the constant term. Is that what you are hinting at?